# Binary counter using for loop with LEDs in Arduino

Tags: c, binary, arduino, counter, led

I am a beginner at using Arduino and I am trying to count up in binary using LEDs.

My code is:

```
int ledPins[] = {2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
{
  int delaytime = 500;
  int x;
  int mod;
  int index;
  int remain;
  for (x=0; x<512; x++)
  {
   if(x%2 == 1)
   {
    digitalWrite(2,HIGH);
   }
   else
   {
    digitalWrite(2,LOW);
   }
   for (index=1, mod=4, remain=1; index<8; index++, mod*=2, remain+=4)
    {
      if(x%mod>remain)
      { 
        digitalWrite(ledPins[index],HIGH);

      }
      else {
        digitalWrite(ledPins[index], LOW);
      }
    }
  delay(delaytime);
  }
}
```

I want the LED to turn on when x%mod>remain. (e.g. 7%4>1, so LED 3 will turn on)

Someone help me out please. Thank you very much.

Comment: How would I make them do what I want them to do? I want mod to be multiplied by 2 and remain to increase by 4

Comment: @GregHewgill Thanks. I thought that would work, but for some reason now the first LED stays on and then a couple others come on later. This happens now even when i put the code back to how it was.

Comment: Well you might want to review your algorithm that determines which LEDs should be lit. I'm not quite sure what your `x%mod>remain` condition is actually supposed to check, but it doesn't seem to be doing bit extraction. I would rewrite that loop using operators like `&` and `<<` (search for "print number in binary" or similar for more details).

Comment: @GregHewgill man, I must be tired. I messed up all my checks. I want to mod the number and if it is greater than a number, the led is lit (e.g. 6%4=2, 2>1 so LED 1 will turn on). I used >> to check, and now they are all on and the first 4 leds seem to be blinking in some kind of patter that makes no sense.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using the modulo operator '%', you can use bit-wise operations. For instance, the following writes the current value of x to your LEDs:

```
for(i=0; i<8; i++)
{
    digitalWrite(ledPins[i], (x >> i) & 0x01);
}
```

There are two operations involved here, a bitwise shift to the right (">>") and a bit-wise AND ("&").

For instance, let's imagine we want to get bit 3 of the number 170. The following shows how the number is manipulated in binary:

```
(original value of x)   10101010
(after bitwise shift 3) 00010101
(after bitwise and 1)   00000001
```

For more information search for "bitwise operators" or "bit masks".

To figure out why your approach didn't work, the best way is to dry run it by choosing a value for x and working through what would happen on paper like I did above. At a glance, it looks wrong to me that you're always adding 4 to the remainder each loop.

When the pins are contiguous on a port, you can simply assign the value of x directly to the port; this is what Bappi was getting at. This works because under-the-hood micro-controllers store multiple pin values in a single register.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that pint 9 is LSD and pin 2 is MSD, try following code.

```
LEDControlLoop(){

    int x = 0;
    int delaytime = 500;
    DDRD = B11111111; // sets port d as output

    while(1){ // infinte while loop,
        PORTD = x;
        delay(delaytime);
        x++;
        if(x>255){
            x = 0;
            //break; //optional
        }   
    }
}
```